# How do I stop variables from overwriting in nodejs when requiring them on a main file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I have multiple scripts that are almost the same but with different parameters on a 'params' object set on top level. When I require() the scripts on the same file to run them at the same time, the 'params' object gets overwriten and only the last required 'params' is used. How do I stop this?

File 1:

```
params = {
        name: "John",
        salary: "50"
    }
```

File 2:

```
params = {
        name: "Victoria",
        salary: "10"
    }
```

File 3:

```
params = {
        name: "Veka",
        salary: "80"
    }
```

Main file:

```
require(file1.js)();
require(file2.js)();
require(file3.js)();
// do things
```

I know I could change the name for every file, but I think Im missing something. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the desired behavior? You seem to have one global variable and it naturally can't hold several distinct values at once.
If you need to have access to data provided by all three files and you **need** it to be a global variable (as opposed to, say, making your files into value-returning functions) then you can instead make it an array or object that the individual files insert into.

### Array:

Main file before require calls:

```js
params = []
```

File 1 (same for other files):

```js
params.push({
    name: "John",
    salary: 50
});
```

### Object:

Main file:

```js
params = {}
```

File 1:

```js
params['file1'] = {
    name: "John",
    salary: 50
};
```

---

### Alternative

Use of globals is discouraged unless absolutely necessary because they lead to confusing bugs and are hard to debug. Instead, you can do:

File 1

```js
function getData() {
  return {
    name: 'John',
    salary: 50
  };
}
module.exports = getData;
```

Main file:

```
const file1Data = require('./file1.js')();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one more doubt. If I happen to have the same function on every file, if I require the files on a main file, all the functions will get replaced by the last 'require' right? I tried to use module.exports to export all the content with anonymous functions but they seem to share context anyways. Is there no way of dealing with it, or separate context? I only want to get individual contexts. I guess I could run every file separated instead of requiring them together as a las resort.

Comment: Not at all, as long as you use them the way I showed above, they should stay several separate functions and not overwrite each other. Here's a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/node-playground-forked-2q6nu?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand closure and variable scope in Javascript.

Here an interresting [articles](https://javascript.info/closure).

So, you need to encapsulate those variable in their own function.

```
const yourFunctionFile1 = () => {
   const params = {
        name: "Veka",
        salary: "80"
    }
   // do whatever you want
}
module.exports = yourFunctionFile1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export the params object in each file and then require them in your main file as variables:

File 1:

```js
module.exports.params = {
  name: "John",
  salary: "50"
}
```

File 2:

```js
module.exports.params = {
  name: "Victoria",
  salary: "10"
}
```

Main file:

```js
let params1 = require('./file1').params
let params2 = require('./file2').params
```